# duckdb (0.7.0) not supporting PEP 517 builds

Tags: python, docker, dockerfile, python-poetry, duckdb

I'm trying to dockerize my backend so I can upload it on AWS lambda but I'm encountering this error constantly.
`Note: This error originates from the build backend, and is likely not a problem with poetry but with duckdb (0.7.0) not supporting PEP 517 builds. You can verify this by running 'pip wheel --use-pep517 "duckdb (==0.7.0)"'.` When I execute the command `pip wheel --use-pep517 "duckdb (==0.7.0)"` it generates a .whl file so I guess that the duckdb version is correct but I don't know what my problem could be. Firsly I used the Duckdb version 0.7.1 which had the exact same error, but I don't know if I just have to keep downgrading to a version that works because that can also 'ruin' my project.
The error is at `RUN  poetry config virtualenvs.create false && poetry install --no-dev --no-interaction --no-  ansi`
This is my Dockerfile

```
FROM public.ecr.aws/lambda/python:3.9-arm64

ENV POETRY_VERSION=1.4.2

RUN pip install "poetry==$POETRY_VERSION"

WORKDIR ${LAMBDA_TASK_ROOT}
COPY poetry.lock pyproject.toml ${LAMBDA_TASK_ROOT}/
# Install the function's dependencies using file requirements.txt
# from your project folder.

RUN  poetry config virtualenvs.create false && poetry install --no-dev --no-interaction --no- 
ansi

# Copy function code
COPY app.py ${LAMBDA_TASK_ROOT}
COPY scraper_backend ${LAMBDA_TASK_ROOT}/scraper_backend

# Set the CMD to your handler (could also be done as a parameter override outside of the 
Dockerfile)
CMD [ "app.handler" ]
```

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: I'm not sure if it's the root cause, but poetry doesn't recommend installing poetry with pip. You could try to follow this image https://binx.io/2022/06/13/poetry-docker/  example. Another possible issue is that duckdb doesn't provide wheels for arm64 linux .

Comment: @0x26res love seeing xebia links, but its dead :)